# What is this U.V. artifact?

Tags: uv

So, I was just trying to really start mastering U.V. Unwrapping.  I was following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/49955/blender-tutorial-for-beginners-how-to-make-a-mushroom) tutorial.  However, whenever I select the top of the mushroom and U.V. unwrap it: I get these strange artifacts in my mesh.  The overall screenshot can be seen here: [image] and you can see that I've highlighted the problem here: [image]

What causes this, and how do I get rid of it?  (I assume that I should.)  What effect will this have on my wraps if left alone?

Comment: This is a face of the mushroom which isn't unwrapped properly so it's stretched very much. You can use `Keep UV and edit mode selection in Sync` button in UV/Image Editor, switch to face seletion mode and see which face exactly hasn't been unwrapped good enough (simply by selecting that glitchy stretched face from your screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say exactly what the items are that are perplexing you. One possibility is that they may be one or more faces on the inside of your mesh that you created by accident. If this is the case, you might locate them by switching to wireframe mode. To see if it's a poorly unwrapped face, switch to textured mode in the 3D viewport, and move the point that is active in the UV editor window and see where the texture on the textured mesh moves.